# Gadgeteer, importing specific GHI Electronics library

Tags: c#, .net-gadgeteer, gadgeteer

I got my hands on gadgeteer and I am just trying to play with it little bit. 
I am trying to get this code to work
[.Net Gadgeteer Camera, Touch Screen and Storage](http://mikedodaro.net/2011/10/13/net-gadgeteer-camera-touchscreen-storage/)

Everything seems to be fine except it looks like I missing the GHI electronics library. I followed all the instructions on the GHI electronics website and I still seem to have error on line

`using GHIElectronics.NETMF.System;`

It says "The type or name 'NETMF' does not exist in the namespace 'GHIElectronics' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Only reason why its not working that i can come up with that I'm running new version of the SDK. I am new to c# so I might be missing something else as well. Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: So `are you missing an assembly reference?` Specifically, did you add a reference from your project to GHIElectronics.NETMF.System.dll?

Comment: ehm how do I do that?

Comment: Click on `References` in Solution Explorer, `Add Reference...` navigate to where the assembly is located and select it (looks to be in Program Files from [this](http://mikedodaro.net/2011/10/13/net-gadgeteer-camera-touchscreen-storage/)).

Comment: yea its in C:\Program Files (x86)\GHI Electronics\GHI NETMF v4.1 SDK\Assemblies\be
ill give it a go didnt know i had to do this

Comment: Thanks I managed. I am getting one more error, whenever there is "button" mentioned in the code. It just says "The Name 'button' does not exit in the current context"

I am slightly confused because he uses the touch screen as a button.

Comment: That's a different issue. Post a new question if you can't figure it out.